# How to develop new features for rails app without affecting existing website

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

I have recently launched version 1 of my web application and it is currently online and im getting a small amount of traffic on a daily basis. I now need to start developing new features for my application and also have the ability to test these features online on heroku without affecting the existing website until the feature is fully developed and ready to go live. How can I do this? Is it as simple as creating a new branch with git? Or is there a way to have a seperate url that only I can access in which I can push these new features and test them out before pushing it to my main site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I notice heroku provide some [Managing Multiple Environments for an App](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/multiple-environments#starting-from-an-existing-app), but actually I didn't follow this guide, but you may find it helpful.

What I did for my last project is to have a git branch called staging and another heroku app runs the staging website, therefore I can run my  UI testing or feature integration in the staging app (the extra url as you mentioned) without breaking the real website.

Afterwards, I merge into the *master* branch from the *staging* branch if the feature functions are bug-free. I am not sure this a good way to do it, just me personly found it very helpful, especially for online payment, whose test requires more than localhost developmemt.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! Can I just ask, if you are using the same source code, how do you push your code to different urls? In other words, how can I have seperate urls for the same project? sorry this is probably a very noob question but it would be great if you could explain that part for me.